# Twilio Function Read Multiple Speech Input

Tags: c#, twilio

The use case is the call an IVR system using programmable voice in twilio. Based the IVR question, send answers using twilio function and TWIML. How can I achieve this? So far I have made call using Twilio and refer below the callback webhook.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public TwiMLResult Index(string message)
    {
        var response = new VoiceResponse(); 

        var gather = new Gather(input: new List<Gather.InputEnum>()
        {
            Gather.InputEnum.Speech
        } , 
            timeout: 5,  action:new Uri("https://url-sample/GatherSample"));

        gather.Say("Please press 1 or say sales for sales.");
        response.Append(gather);
        LogWriter.Debug($"Message : {response.ToString()}");
        return new TwiMLResult(response);
    }
```

Also Twilio Function Code.

```
    exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  const command = event.SpeechResult.toLowerCase();

  twiml.say(`You said ${command}. I'll give you a ${command} fact.`);

  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Comment: Answer to this is not a simple. You should refer twilio documentation for this and try to implement and come back here if you face any specific issue in that..https://www.twilio.com/docs/interactive-voice-response and https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/ivr-phone-tree-csharp-mvc

Comment: Are you finding any errors with this so far? If you are having difficulty with this, then we can help, but if you are just exploring I recommend you keep doing so and follow the tutorials that Chetan has linked to above.